# How to gather statistics and extract data from an email list discussion system?

Tags: mailing-lists

My company is using emails lists to discuss topics in a very Stack Exchange way. As you could easily guess, we are missing some key features like: votes and statistics.

So, I'm looking for a way for our email based system to;

1. Gather statistics about: number of unique topics, number of answers, best contributor, best topic (based on the number of answers) ... 
   I was thinking about extracting data to Excel and then process it. But before selling my soul to the devil, I prefer to look for a clean way to do things.
2. Provide a way to "vote" for the best answer.
   I was thinking about sending emails to a special email address, with a predefined format: + (upvote) - (downvote). But it requires to process data to make connection between messages and votes, and I'm quite short in time.

So, even if I would prefer to have a real Q&A system, I need to find a way to improve our solution.

If you have any hint to start with, or any suggestion, I would really appreciate.

PS: English is not really my mother tongue, so please accept my apology concerning grammar, spelling and punctuation.

Comment: Email really wasn't designed for this sort of thing.